# Taxi from Paris Orly airport

Tags: paris, taxis, ory

Could anybody advise me on the estimated price of taxi from Orly airport to Place Denfert-Rochereau and from Orly airport to the Pasteur metro station? We are 2 adult plus the teenager. I would like to use the Orlybus but I am worried we can miss it.

Have all the taxis a same pricing?

We will arrive at 10:50pm, May 7, 2014, hopefuly it is the night before a holiday with prolonged service of public transport. Does anybody know???

Comment: According to rome2rio getting getting to [Denfert-Rochereau](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Paris-Orly/Place-Denfert-Rochereau) costs around 20 Eur. The same estimation is given for [pasteur metro](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Paris-Orly/Pasteur-75015-Paris-France)

Comment: Hi Flimzy...because of the time - our arrival is at 10:50 p.m. if we miss the last orlybus we miss even metro. but if the May 7th is really night before holiday, we could catch both. K.

Comment: Thank you Andra! We will arrive at 22:50 and last Orly bus should go at 23:30. If the May 7th is day before holiday really it should be at 0:30. If the flight has even 30 minutes delay, I guess we don't have any other poss than taxi.

Comment: thanks you... we will arrive to Paris/Ory on May 7th 2014 - this week on Wednesday...

Answer (score 3):

If you hail an "official" taxi in front of the airport you can expect [between 40 and 55 EUR for a drive from Orly to Paris intra muros plus 15% for a drive in the evening](http://www.aeroportsdeparis.fr/en/passengers/access/paris-orly/taxi/taxi). Denfert-Rochereau will be on the lower bound of the quoted prices. Pasteur a bit further away.

I found for the date you specified a quote from a taxi company, between 26 and 31 EUR from Orly Sud to Denfert-Rochereau and 34 to 42 EUR to the Pasteur Metro Station.

You can also hire a limousine service, a so-called "[VTC](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiture_de_tourisme_avec_chauffeur)" (voiture de tourisme avec chauffeur), you will have between 35 and 40 EUR from Orly to Paris intra muros (whatever the exact address). VTC services are totally legal in France.

The 20 EUR that have been mentioned by the other person apply to the controversial UberPOP service.